# Build automation for iPad 3 Retina App

Tags: xcode, ipad, automation, resolution, retina-display

I currently prepare an existing iOS app for the new iPad with iOS 5.1 according to https://devforums.apple.com/message/632246

Due to the high resolutions of the retina display graphics the app size of my app increased dramatically. Therefore I want to provide (at least) two versions of the app: a HD version with high resolution images and a "classic" version with lower resolution images.

I'm currently having a project which includes images in ALL four resolutions (iphone, iphone@2x, ipad, ipad@2px).

**My question**: How can I set up an automatic build process which builds separate apps which only include the relevant images (e.g. an app "TestApp iPhone" with ONLY the small iphone-images, a bigger app "TestApp iPhone HD", an app "TestApp iPad" and a "TestApp iPad HD" with high resolution images).
Do I have to setup this build automation manually? Or does XCode provide a special feature for this? Or is there any other Apple product or Third Party product out there which provides such a functionality?

Comment: Is this a free app? Otherwise your customers might not be happy having to buy the app repeatedly for multiple/new devices. You might be able to avoid this trouble with better compression of your images (it'll still be bigger, but not unreasonably so): see http://imageoptim.com

Comment: Yes it is a free app and the images already have really good compression rates. Nevertheless the app size increased significantly when adding iPad HD images. My customers are not willing to download an app with huge images if they only want to use it on a small iPhone without retina.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Xcode create several targets within the same project for each app needed e.g. in your sample project create two targets called `SampleApp` and `SampleAppHd`. Add the relevant images for each target in the target settings: Select the target `SampleAppHd`, click tab `Build phases` - `copy bundle resources` - `Add items` - `Add other`. Use the finder filter to filter only those images containing `@2x` and add them. Similiary you can use the filter box in the tab `Build phases` to remove images containing `@2x` from a not-HD-target.

Once the targets are setup correctly you can use them for building separate apps (e.g. `SampleApp` and `SampleAppHd`) using your automatic build process.